# Не работает ScrollZoom в яндекс картах

Tags: javascript, html, css3, yandex-maps-api

Не работает масштабирование карты, если крутить колесико. Мой код:

**HTML**

```
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    height: 100%;
}

#map {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**JS**

```
ymaps.ready(function () {
        var clusterer = new ymaps.Clusterer({gridSize: 128});

        var map = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [59.938978, 30.315943],
            zoom: 10,
            controls: ["zoomControl"]
        });

        map.geoObjects.add(clusterer);    

    });
```

Карта загружается, центр выставляется правилно, зум самой карты (интерфейс) работает, но если скролить, то ничего не происходит. Ошибок в консоли нет. Что делать?

Comment: А что если попробовать убрать строку `controls: ["zoomControl"]` и добавить новую строку после создания карты, вида: `map.controls.add('zoomControl', { top: 75, left: 5 });` все также не работает?

Comment: @DenisBubnov да, и даже если оставить только `zoom` и `center`, появляется карта с дефолтовыми элементами а scroll zoom не работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поменял src на url карт, как у них в примере, и все заработало.

Через `requirejs` это `//api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?load=package.full&lang=ru-RU`

До этого у меня локально в проекте лежал скриптик карт.

Comment: всё правильно сделали, сохранять скрипт JS API и запускать локально нельзя - это и запрещено условиями использования, и грозит кучей технических проблем